# what is a better way to run docker under chronos?

Tags: mesos, dcos

I have a dockerized spring-boot app, which needs to be scheduled in mesos / chronos (DC/OS).
There are 2 places, which (I think) can be used to accomplish Chronos scheduling:

1) by using the "command" tag
2) by using the "container" tag

An example of Chronos command tag would be:

```
{
    "name": "my-dockerized-app",
    "command": "docker login -u my_username -p my_password -e dev-my_user@my_company.com;docker run -e id=123 my_owner/my_dockerized_app_image:latest",
    "shell": true,
    "epsilon": "PT60S",
    "executor": "",
    "executorFlags": "",
    "retries": 2,
    "owner": "",
    "ownerName": "",
    "description": "",
    "async": false,
    "successCount": 0,
    "errorCount": 264,
    "lastSuccess": "",
    "lastError": "",
    "cpus": 0.5,
    "disk": 256.0,
    "mem": 512.0,
    "disabled": false,
    "softError": false,
    "dataProcessingJobType": false,
    "errorsSinceLastSuccess": 264,
    "uris": [],
    "environmentVariables": [{
        "name": "id",
        "value": "1"
    }],
    "arguments": [],
    "highPriority": false,
    "runAsUser": "root",
    "constraints": [],
    "schedule": "R/2016-11-21T05:06:00.000Z/PT2M",
    "scheduleTimeZone": ""
}
```

An example of Chronos "container" tag:

```
  {
     "schedule": "R\/2014-09-25T17:22:00Z\/PT2M",
     "name": "my_docker_job",
     "container": {
      "type": "DOCKER",
      "image": "my_owner/my_dockerized_app",
      "network": "BRIDGE"
     },
     "cpus": "0.5",
     "mem": "512",
     "uris": [],
     ""
    }
```

Which of these scheduling methods should really be used in Mesos / Chronos production environments?

Comment: Did you have a look at DC/OS [Jobs](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/jobs/) yet? Going forward, that prolly the best option.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use second option**

The difference in this two configurations is the way Mesos will interact with docker.

1. you are creating Mesos task that is launching docker so Mesos doesn't know about docker and you need to monitor it.
2. Mesos will launch docker for you and keep a track of it. So if docker fails Mesos will notify Chronos.